# Why does appending to a file insert whitespace (NUL)

Tags: powershell

I am running this command

```
Get-Content generated\no_animate.css >> generated\all.css
```

I want to append the contents of `no_animate.css` to `all.css`.

This is working if I run it like this from a cmd prompt:

```
powershell Get-Content generated\no_animate.css >> generated\all.css
```

If I put the exact same code into a .ps1 file and run that it is copying the contents but inserting whitespace (Represented as NUL in texteditor) between every character.

Why would it be doing this? How do I prevent it?

Comment: It's writing the output file as Unicode (UCS-2 or UTF-16). Why don't you just use `copy foo.css bar.css`?

Comment: Copy is overwriting the file, i want to append the contents of `foo.css` to the end of `bar.css`

Comment: Good point. I kinda skipped over the `>>`. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell the [redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) `>` and `>>` are shorthands for `Out-File` and `Out-File -Append` respectively. [`Out-File`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx) uses [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (little endian UTF-16 specifically) as its default encoding. With this encoding every character is represented by 2 bytes instead of just 1. For ASCII characters (characters from the [basic latin](http://unicode.org/charts/) block) the first byte has the value 0.

Running `powershell Get-Content generated\no_animate.css >> generated\all.css` from CMD uses the [CMD redirection operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) instead of the PowerShell one, which doesn't transform the text to Unicode.

If you want to use PowerShell and your input file is ascii-encoded use [`Add-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849859.aspx) (available in PowerShell v3 or newer):

```
Get-Content generated\no_animate.css | Add-Content generated\all.css
```

or `Out-File` with explicit encoding.

```
Get-Content generated\no_animate.css |
    Out-File generated\all.css -Append -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: When i try this i am getting this `powershell Get-Content generated\no_animate.css | Add-Content generated\all.css' Add-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` . So i tried it from a .ps1 file and it did not error but both that and the command with the explicit encoding added NUL spaces. I tried getting the powershell version from both the cmd line and .ps1 file and it said 3.0.-1.-1

Comment: Seems i needed different encoding afterall. When i set it to OEM using `Get-Content generated\no_animate.css | Out-File generated\all.css -Append -Encoding OEM` it was not inserting Nulls anymore.

Comment: `powershell Get-Content generated\no_animate.css | Add-Content generated\all.css` is running from CMD. `|` is a pipe in CMD. So you're having PowerShell read the content of your file, hand that over to CMD, which pipes it into a command `Add-Content` that doesn't exist. Hence the error you observed.

Comment: Makes sense, so how do you make poweshell handle the whole line, quotes does not work, nor does ( ) brackets.

Comment: I tell a lie, single quotes does not work, double quotes do. Man im such a shell newbie.

Comment: PowerShell supports both double and single quotes, CMD only double quotes.